# SSO in React-Django and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, django-rest-framework, single-sign-on

I have developed a website using React as frontend and Django as backend. Now I have a website already built in WordPress.

My task is to implement SSO for these two platforms. Also the users have registered themselves in React-Django site.

How can I go through this such that the users don't have to register again and using the data in Django, I can facilitate user to access the WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have SAML support implemented on your React-Django sites then you can set up WordPress SSO using this WordPress SAML SP SSO Plugin offered by miniOrange.
You can find this WordPress SSO plugin here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/miniorange-saml-20-single-sign-on/

You will need to configure the React-Django website as your Identity Provider (IDP) and WordPress as Service Provider (SP), you can then setup registration / Login into WordPress using login credentials of React-Django.

I believe they also provide custom solutions if you do not support SAML on your Django site yet.